# Can't override method in Sqlalchemy inherited class

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm struggling with something which I suspect is really simple, because it's an obvious use-case and I can't see anything relevant in the sqlalchemy docs.

I have set up a SourceArchive class, which inherits from SourceFile. They use a joined table approach, as per this page: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html.

```
import os
import json
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, orm
import py7zlib
import filesys_ops
from db_base import Base

# Base = declarative_base()


class SourceDir(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'source_dirs'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    dir_path = Column(String)
    # files = relationship(SourceFile)

    def __init__(self, dir_path):
        self.dir_path = dir_path

    def get_files(self):
        return filesys_ops.read_files(self.dir_path)


class SourceFile(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'source_file'

    # Create a 'rom_names' variable, verify on instantiation and then add to obj.
    # Then have consistent 'get_names' method across subclasses
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    full_path = Column(String)
    name = Column(String)
    # type = Column(String)
    parent_dir_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('source_dirs.id'))
    type = Column(String(50))

    def __init__(self, file_path, parent_dir):
        self.full_path = file_path
        # path, self.name = os.path.split(self.full_path)
        # self.type = magic.from_file(self.full_path)
        self.parent_dir_id = parent_dir.id

    def ext(self):
        base_name, extension = os.path.splitext(self.name)
        return extension

    # @orm.reconstructor
    # def init_on_load(self):
    #     pass

    def get_rom_names(self):
        print('super')
        return [self.name]

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'source_file',
        'polymorphic_on': type
    }


class SourceArchive(SourceFile):

    __tablename__ = 'source_archive'

    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('source_file.id'),     primary_key=True)
    members_json = Column(String)

    def __init__(self, file_path, parent_dir):
        super().__init__(file_path, parent_dir)
        file = open(file_path, 'rb')
        archive = py7zlib.Archive7z(file)
        members = archive.getnames()
        self.members_json = json.dumps(members)
        # print(self.members_json)
            # print(type(self.members_json))
            # print(self.members_json)

    def get_rom_names(self):
        print('or')
        # print('**** - ' + self.members)
        if type(json.loads(self.members_json)) is list:
            return json.loads(self.members_json)
        else:
            return [json.loads(self.members_json)]

    def extractall(self, target_dir):
        for name in self.members:
            self.extract_member(name, target_dir)

    def extract_member(self, member_name, path):
        output_path = os.path.join(path, member_name)
        output_dir = os.path.dirname(output_path)
        filesys_ops.validate_dir(output_dir, create=True)
        outfile = open(output_path, 'wb')
        outfile.write(self.archive.getmember(member_name).read())
        outfile.close()

        __mapper_args__ = {
            'polymorphic_identity': 'source_archive',
        }
```

Once the database has been populated with a combination of SourceFile and SourceArchive objects I am using the following code to retrieve them:

```
all_files = with_polymorphic(SourceFile, SourceArchive)

query = session.query(all_files)

source_files = query.all()
```

This only returns SourceFile objects though, with the result that any call to the 'get_roms' method calls the SourceFile implementation.

In a previous version of the code I didn't use the boilerplate from the linked tutorial and just approached the class inheritance as I would with general Python, in some cases sharing a table, in others not. I could then return all objects as SourceFiles or all as SourceArchives, just depending on which I queried, with the same results (though it was also possible to call SourceArchive's implementation of get_roms on a SourceFile object too).

If anybody can help I'd be very grateful,

Comment: Are you sure that your database doesn't, in fact, only contain rows with type `source_file`?

Comment: Thank you for your help univerio, appreciated. I've just come back to this problem this afternoon and discovered that I hadn't properly set up SqlAlchemy's polymorphism. It worked when I set the base class (SourceFile) 'polymorphic_identity' to 'None'.